# Using scalars in regex search

Tags: regex, perl, scalar

I wrote this code:

```
my $id = shift;
my $file = shift;
unless(open (INFO, $file)) { print "cant open file\n"; return 0; }
#this is how i do it - i didn't copy the code directly last time:
while(my $line = <info>)
{
    if($line =~ /d\s+S+\s\Q$id\disk\d+s\d+/g)
    {
        print "yay i found it";
        close(INFO);
        return 1;
    }
}
close(INFO);
return 0;
```

Example for a line that would be good is:

```
2:     Apple_HFS 0x123456789ABC   999.9 GB   disk2s2
```

(as u can see $id is "0x123456789ABC")

My question: it doesn't work  - it opens the file and read the lines but the maching isn't good. please tell me what am  I missing here? I guess my regex is wrong but I couldn't fix it.

I tried google and (of course) Stack overflow ([How to evaluate a word saved in a scalar via regular expression in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957609/how-to-evaluate-a-word-saved-in-a-scalar-via-regular-expression-in-perl) , [Detect exact string value of scalar in regex matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365906/detect-exact-string-value-of-scalar-in-regex-matching) , [Use variable as RegEx pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041877/use-variable-as-regex-pattern)) but with no luck.
I'm sure I'm missing some basics but this isn't my first regex - just the firs to have a scalar in it.

Thank you

Comment: `$file` is the *name* of the file. You open it but never actually *read* anything from it. And your regex doesn't take account of the size field `999.9 GB` in each record

Comment: thank you all. my original problem was the regex itself. all of you helped with that. @Borodin 's answer also provided me with a more 'pleasant' solution. his comments also taught me some important things. so I mark his answer as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `$file` is the name of the file. You open it but never actually read anything from it.

Here are some further comments on your code

- It is common practice, and much tidier, to collect the parameters of a subroutine like this

  ```
  my ($id, $file) = @_
  ```

  This also has the advantage of copying the values, so that the actual parameters in the call are in less danger of being modified
- You should use the three-parameter form of `open` and lexical file handles, like this

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $file
  ```

  In particular, the file is left open when the subroutine exits in your case because you have chosen a global file handle. Lexical handles are closed implicitly when they go out of scope
- You should use the `$!` built-in variable in the `open` error message to give information on *why* it failed
- An error is generally indicated by a bare `return`, which returns `undef` or an empty list, dependent on context. `return 0` in list context results in the list `(0)` which produces a *true* value if it is assigned to an array
- Unless you *really* need to be able to access all of a file at once, it is generally best to use a `while` loop to read and process it line by line
- The `/g` regex match modifier is for finding *all* occurrences of a pattern in a string. It is unnecessary and wasteful if all you want to do is check whether the pattern appears *anywhere* in the string

Also your regex has a lot of problems. If I add the `/x` modifier then I can add spaces to show you better what you have written

```
/ d \s+ S+ \s \Q$id \d isk \d+ s \d+ /x
```

which matches

- a single `d` character
- one or more space characters
- one or more `S` characters
- a single space character
- The `\Q` isn't terminated, so the rest of the string is matched literally. If you had `\Q$id\E` then the rest of the pattern would match
- a single digit
- the string `isk`
- one or more digits
- a single `s` character
- one or more digits

which doesn't come close to matching the record format that you show. It's important to remember that there is no need for your pattern to matc *all* of the string, so you may want something like just `/\b\Q$id\E\b/` which checks that your ID is somewhere in the string with word boundaries at each end. I Don't see a string like `0x123456789ABC` appearing elsewhere and giving a false positive

I think the best solution is to split each record on whitespace and check whether the third field matches the ID passed in

Your subroutine should look like this

```
sub routine {
  my ($id, $file) = @_;

  open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
    warn "Unable to open '$file' for input: $!";
    return;
  };

  while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @fields = split ' ', $line;
    if ($fields[2] eq $id) {
      print "Yay! I found it!\n";
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
my @lines = split(/\n/, $file);
```

try

```
my @lines = <INFO>;
```

or even better,

```
unless(open (my $INFO, "<", $file)) { print "cant open file\n"; return 0; }
while (my $line = <$INFO>)
{
  # ..
}
```

Also you've forgot to end quotation of string ie. `\Q$string\E`

```
if($line =~ /d\s+S+\s\Q$id\Edisk\d+s\d+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex is incorrect. I'm not really sure what you're trying to match so I've had an attempt based on the example:

`\d+:.*S\s+\Q$id\E.+disk\d+s\d+`

This will match:

`d+:` a digit followed by a colon

`.*S\s+` everything up to the 'S' in 'Apple_HFS' and a space

`\Q$id\E` the id string you're looking for

`.+` everything up to 'disk'

`disk\d+s\d+` diskXXXsXXX

Works in this snippet:

```
$id = "0x123456789ABC";
$line = "2:     Apple_HFS 0x123456789ABC   999.9 GB   disk2s2";

if($line =~ /\d+:.*S\s+\Q$id\E.+disk\d+s\d+/g)
{
        print "yay i found it";
}
```